# How do I select only the SSID that I need

Tags: android

I have written the code that detects the available nearby Wifi routers and shows up their SSID and BSSID. But i don want to show up everything. I need only the routers of certain SSID. How do i filter them?i am trying to use match the strings but it not helping. please help me guys

Comment: Show your code.  To compare Strings in Java, Make sure you are using the .equals() method not the "==" operator.

Comment: Please read this advice on asking good questions: [ask] and [Writing the perfect question](http://goo.gl/1tBMnR). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Answer (score 0):

You can try filter the SSID

```
private ArrayList<String> getListOfMyConnetions(){

    ArrayList<String> listOfMyConnections = new ArrayList<String>;

    List<ScanResult> scanResults = wifi.getScanResults();
    if (scanResults != null) {
        for(ScanResult s : scanResults) {
            //"CONNECTION_NAME" is the name of SSID you would like filter
            if (s.SSID != null && s.SSID.contains(CONNECTION_NAME)) {
                listOfMyConnections.add( s.SSID );
            }
        }
    }  

    return listOfMyConnections;
}
```